Error trying to install S.u.S.E. Linux 5.2 in VirtualBox 7.0.16
Trying to install S.u.S.E. Linux 5.2 under VirtualBox 7.0.16 I get an error when installing the selected packages: "package aaa_base-98.5.20-0 is for a different architecture... ABORTED":
YaST error message
VirtualBox settings are

1 CPU (Execution Cap 50%)
128 MP Base Memory
PIIX3 Chipset
no TPM
'None' under Acceleration
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA (3D Acceleration disabled)
Storage Controller: IDE (Type: PIIX3) with 2 drives
2GB .vdi is 'IDE Primary Device 0'
ISO with SuSE Linux 5.2 as 'IDE Secondary Device 0'

Any hint appreciated, what I need to change to make it run.

32 or 64 bit Suse? I half suspect PIIX3 might be 32 bit

https://en.opensuse.org/Archive:S.u.S.E._Linux_5.2 : "S.u.S.E. Linux 5.2 was released on Monday, March 23, 1998. "  . Is that really this version that is attempted to be installed? Maybe the issue is the reverse then (too recent platform)

So be sure to run as a 32 bit VM (rather than a 64 bit booted in 32 bit mode or something like this). Maybe you'd have more chances with QEMU (eg https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/i386/pc.html#i440fx-pc-pc-i440fx-pc which is probably the one you're trying)?

S.u.S.E. Linux 5.2 has been released a while ago in 1998 indeed. Have tried QEMU/Gnome Boxes and it also produces same error. Have tried a slightly more recent S.u.S.E. 6.4 from 2000 and same architecture error in that relic...

Have found a YouTube channel showing how-to install old SuSE-Linux's using PCem: https://youtu.be/HukHpD_T2MM?si=G6UBIvf4FIxsK1uV. Will install & use PCem, but would much rather have all my old & new OS's in VirtualBox...

Sorry, I just undid my edit. I hadn't realized you were actually trying to install something that old.

@Zaphod49 [BTW, why 49 and not 42? 6x9...]

Starting to think so as well. As I have some further old Linux retail boxes coming in today (pure nostalgia :)) I will dig into QEMU/KVM a lot more: it should be possible to emulate i386 as performance is not that much of an issue for 20+ year old distress...
